# CPU temperature spikes over 75c

Tags: cpu, performance, temperature, overheating

I've a PC with Windows 10, CPU: AMD FX-3870 8-Core 4GHz, air-cooled by Arctic Freezer A11 (non-stock), and GPU: Sapphire Radeon R9 380 ... I'm trying to figure what exactly is considered damaging temperatures for my PC (using Open Hardware Monitor app for sensors logging).

The CPU idles at ~**23c** and GPU idles at ~**50c** -- so no problem there.

Under heavy load (games) temps average at ~**62c** for the CPU and ~**80c** for the GPU -- within the safe range as far as I know.

However, CPU temperature can briefly spike up to **78c**, logged about ~50 spikes per hour under load.
So, are those spikes normal? are they dangerous? If so, What can I do about it?

Thanx, in advance :)

Comment: If the CPU isn't being throttled due to the temperatures then the temperatures are within it's designed specifications.  AMD does not published the specifications.  If you are not having a specific problem then you should assume the temperatures are normal.

Comment: 78c under load isn't terrible. The spikes could be just points in your game where your PC is working harder, due to more content on screen, physics-heavy scenes, etc. However if you'd see these spikes while idle that might be cause for concern

Comment: 78c is not that bad. When you say it's air cooled, are you using the stock CPU cooler or a different one?

Comment: @DrZoo The CPU cooler is Arctic Freezer A11 (non-stock). There's no throttling, slow-downs or specific issues that I can see. Performance is steady.